Unable to decompress byte array into a memory stream
I'm trying to write a simple function that receives a byte array (a GZipped file) and returns a MemoryStream of the uncompressed file:
Private Function DecompressByteArray(bytes As Byte()) As System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim srcStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim destStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream

    'load byte array into memory stream object
    srcStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)  'This works fine.

    Dim gz As New GZipStream(srcStream, CompressionMode.Decompress)
    Dim bytesRead As Integer
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(10000) {}
    bytesRead = gz.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)  'returns zero bytes read!
    While bytesRead <> 0
        destStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
        bytesRead = gz.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    End While
    gz.Close()
    srcStream.Close()

    Return destStream
End Function

As noted in the comments, the gz.read() operation isn't returning any bytes. So, the memory stream that is returned is empty.
I've used nearly identical code only with FileStream objects with no problem.  But I can't get this to work with MemoryStream objects.  I'm doing everything in memory (receiving the byte array from an API) so FileStream objects don't fit the bill.

Dim srcStream As New MemoryStream(bytes) srcStream.Position = 0 -- How come you're receiving GZip-ped data? Are you using HttpClient / WebRequest? Did you forget to set them up to receive (and of course auto-decompress) the incoming stream? Both provide an AutomaticDecompression property (the former through the Handler)

BTW, since you're already receiving a byte array, so everything lives in memory in any case, you can remove the clutter and just have gz.CopyTo(destStream). This in the (weird) case you can do nothing about how the data is received, that is

As Jimi indicates, you need to seek to the start of the stream, which you can do by setting the Position or calling Seek. That should be enough on its own, but there does seem little point creating the stream and then writing to it when you can create it with the data from the start.

Thanks @Jimi.  Using CopyTo() worked!

Thanks to Jimi for his comment to use the CopyTo() method instead!  New function:
Public Function Decompress(ByVal bSource As Byte()) As MemoryStream ' Byte()
    Dim inStream As New MemoryStream(bSource)
    Dim gzip As New GZipStream(inStream, CompressionMode.Decompress)
    Dim outStream As New MemoryStream()
    gzip.CopyTo(outStream)
    Return outStream
End Function


A gzip stream uses native memory, you should dispose of it correctly.
